# Replace breaker For hot water heater

Tags: electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, water-heater

My tankless hot water heater went out & is on, I believe, a double 60 amp breaker. My plumber says the new one needs a 50 amp breaker. Can I just swap out the 60 amp with a new double 50 amp breaker?

Comment: This seems slightly strange.  Is the new heater more efficient, or are you downsizing a bit?

Comment: The new heater is more efficient & calls for a 50 amp breaker.

Answer (score 3):

You can breaker down but not up, so yes, you can just replace the 60 with a 50, the wires should fit. Before you do that though, check with the installation instructions to verify what your plumber wants you to do. The instructions  will specify what size breaker you need to have and changing those directions can void any warranties you might have.

Comment: Thank you,   The new heater does call for a 50 amp breaker